# Get current zoom level from QGIS map canvas

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

Is there any particular way of getting the current zoom level from the map canvas through python code in **QGIS** environment?
I want to convert coordinates of the cursor and the current zoom level into Google Map Tiles coordinates.

Comment: If you mean scale, you could try `iface.mapCanvas().scale()`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but is there any way I can convert scale to zoom levels?
I need to put zoom levels in my URL to request tiles of the specific regions at specific zoom levels.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using this:

```
import math
scale=iface.mapCanvas().scale()
dpi=iface.mainWindow().physicalDpiX()
maxScalePerPixel = 156543.04
inchesPerMeter = 39.37
zoomlevel = int(round(math.log( ((dpi* inchesPerMeter * maxScalePerPixel) / scale), 2 ), 0))
print zoomlevel
```

Original code : https://github.com/datalyze-solutions/TileMapScaleLevels/blob/master/tilemapscalelevels.py

Answer (score 1):

Just install tile layer plugin then add an XYZ or TMS reference to the map with the plugin you will get zoom column row information
https://github.com/minorua/TileLayerPlugin/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to take account of the "tilePixelRatio". Not all retrieved images will be 256 x 256 px. Some may be 512 x 512 px with tilePixelRatio=2 and will thus have a different zoom value. I'm not sure that QGIS takes this into account anywhere.